# Plot polynomial regression curve in R

Tags: r, plot, lm

I have a simple polynomial regression which I do as follows

```
attach(mtcars)
fit <- lm(mpg ~ hp + I(hp^2))
```

Now, I plot as follows

```
> plot(mpg~hp)
> points(hp, fitted(fit), col='red', pch=20)
```

This gives me the following

[image: Plot of mpg versus hp]

[image: Fitted Values]

I want to connect these points into a smooth curve, using lines gives me the following

```
> lines(hp, fitted(fit), col='red', type='b')
```

[image: Line plot]

What am I missing here. I want the output to be a smooth curve which connects the points

Comment: You really shouldn't use `attach`, it can cause many bugs.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try:

```
lines(sort(hp), fitted(fit)[order(hp)], col='red', type='b')
```

Because your statistical units in the dataset are not ordered, thus, when you use `lines` it's a mess.

Comment: Unless you have evenly spaced values or many observations, using this `fitted()` approach is not going to produce a smooth realisation of the fitted polynomial/function

Comment: @GavinSimpson of course, generating a sequence of close and evenly spaced points, and fitting the function on it would produce a smoother curve. But I think the aim of the question was to find a way to connect the existing fitted points by a line, not the curve itself.

Answer (score 36):

I like to use `ggplot2` for this because it's usually very intuitive to add layers of data.

```
library(ggplot2)
fit <- lm(mpg ~ hp + I(hp^2), data = mtcars)
prd <- data.frame(hp = seq(from = range(mtcars$hp)[1], to = range(mtcars$hp)[2], length.out = 100))
err <- predict(fit, newdata = prd, se.fit = TRUE)

prd$lci <- err$fit - 1.96 * err$se.fit
prd$fit <- err$fit
prd$uci <- err$fit + 1.96 * err$se.fit

ggplot(prd, aes(x = hp, y = fit)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(aes(ymin = lci, ymax = uci), stat = "identity") +
  geom_point(data = mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg))
```

[image]

Comment: When using your code (with R 3.3.3 and ggplot2_2.2.1 sp_1.2-4) I get the Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: ymin, ymax

Comment: @TheThunderChimp they appear to be there... http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html

Comment: This is apparently a bug on recent versions of ggplot2: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1939

Answer (score 17):

Generally a good way to go is to use the `predict()` function. Pick some `x` values, use `predict()` to generate corresponding `y` values, and plot them. It can look something like this:

```
newdat = data.frame(hp = seq(min(mtcars$hp), max(mtcars$hp), length.out = 100))
newdat$pred = predict(fit, newdata = newdat)

plot(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)
with(newdat, lines(x = hp, y = pred))
```

[image]

See Roman's answer for a fancier version of this method, where confidence intervals are calculated too. In both cases the actual *plotting* of the solution is incidental - you can use base graphics or `ggplot2` or anything else you'd like - the key is *just use the predict function to generate the proper y values.* It's a good method because it extends to all sorts of fits, not just polynomial linear models. You can use it with non-linear models, GLMs, smoothing splines, etc. - anything with a `predict` method.

Comment: Whilst not explained as such, Romain's answer already shows this `predict()` approach, does it not?

Comment: Yes it does, but as you say it's *not* explained as such. This seems to be a standard source for this info with many linked duplicates - I think having an *explanation* of the general method is valuable, and I also think that `ggplot` can be a barrier for new R users so it's nice to demo the method using base. But I will edit to acknowledge Roman's efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I found a funny solution.

```
plot(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)
curve(expr = cbind(1, poly(x, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)) %*% fit$coefficients,
      add = TRUE, col = "red")
```

Essentially, it simply applies the matrix definition of a linear regression.

```
a %*% coef = b
```

Here, the matrix `a` can be expressed either way:

```
cbind(1, poly(x, degree = 2, raw = TRUE))
t(sapply(x, `^`, e2 = 0:2))
```

And this works because `curve` takes expressions where `x` is the variable.