# Fit a smooth curve on degree distribution plot

Tags: r, plot, distribution

I plot the degree distribution graph and fit a power law on it, but rather than fitting a power law i want to plot a smooth curve on the middle point of the plot. So i need help for that, how to fit a smooth curve on degree distribution? My code and graph is as below.
Code :

```
rm(list=ls())
options(max.print = 10000000)
library(igraph)

Binr<- read.delim("E:/M.Tech 3rd         sem/Thesis/Dataset/BINARY_PROTEIN_PROTEIN_INTERACTIONS.txt", na.strings="-",
              header=F, comment.char = "" , fill = TRUE , sep = "\t" )
Binrppi <- Binr[complete.cases(Binr),]
d_f <- data.frame(Binrppi$V1 , Binrppi$V4);d_f
lvl <- d_f[as.character(d_f[,1])!= as.character(d_f[,2]),];lvl
g <- graph.data.frame(lvl,directed = FALSE)
d <- degree(g)
degree <- sort(d, decreasing = TRUE)
dd <- degree.distribution(g, cumulative = FALSE)
degree <- 1:max(d);degree
probability <- dd[-1] ; probability
nonzero.position = which(probability != 0)
probability = probability[nonzero.position]
degree = degree[nonzero.position];degree
reg = lm(log(probability) ~ log(degree)) ; reg
cozf = coef(reg);cozf
summary(reg)
alpha = -cozf[[2]]; alpha
R.square = summary(reg)$r.squared
R.square
lo <- loess(degree ~ probability );lo
plot(probability ~ degree, log = "xy", xlab = "Degree", ylab = "Probability (log)", 
 col = "blue", main = "Degree Distribution")
xl <- seq(min(probability),max(probability), (max(probability) -     min(probability))/1000); xl
lines(xl, predict(lo,xl), col='red', lwd=2)
```

Graph :
[image: This the plot of degree distribution.]

In this plot i want a smooth curve in the middle point like from degree 2 to say degree 50
My dataset is too large that's why i am not able to upload it here. Its PPI dataset.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Hello, here i post a small part of my dataset. First 100 interactions are posted.
     Binrppi.V1 Binrppi.V4
     2  ITGA7   CHRNA1
    3   PPP1R9A ACTG1
    4   SRGN    CD44
    5   GRB7    ERBB2
    6   PAK1    ERBB2
    7   DLG4    ERBB2
    8   PIK3R2  ERBB2
    9   PTPN18  ERBB2
    10  ERBB2IP ERBB2
    11  SMURF2  ARHGAP5
    12  NF2     ERBB2
    13  CD82    ERBB2
    14  ERRFI1  ERBB2
    15  MMP7    CD44
    16  TOB1    ERBB2
    17  MUC4    ERBB2
    18  PICK1   ERBB2
    19  SMURF2  TXNIP
    20  DDX20   ETV3
    21  TLE1    FOXG1
    22  TLE3    FOXG1
    23  HDAC1   FOXG1
    24  SMAD1   FOXG1
    25  KDM5B   FOXG1
    26  CD4     CD44
    27  SMURF2  DAB2
    28  CBL     VAV1
    29  PLCG1   VAV1
    30  PRLR    VAV1
    31  TYK2    VAV1
    32  SMURF2  DGCR2
    33  MAPK1   VAV1
    34  VAV1    RHOG
    35  HRAS    VAV1
    36  BTK     VAV1
    37  TGFBR1  CD44
    38  SYK VAV1
    39  SHB VAV1
    40  PRKCQ   VAV1
    41  TEC VAV1
    42  IL6ST   VAV1
    43  HNRNPK  VAV1
    44  SLA VAV1
    45  PTK2B   VAV1
    46  EZH2    VAV1
    47  LCP2    VAV1
    48  TGFBR2  CD44
    49  ZYX VAV1
    50  SH3BP2  VAV1
    51  SIAH2   VAV1
    52  LAT VAV1
    53  ARHGDIB VAV1
    54  SOCS1   VAV1
    55  AOC3    VAV1
    56  NEK3    VAV1
    57  CBLB    VAV1
    58  BLNK    VAV1
    59  VAV2    CD44
    60  RACGAP1 VAV1
    61  PAG1    VAV1
    62  DOCK2   VAV1
    63  SMURF2  FAM175B
    64  SMURF2  ACBD3
    66  PECAM1  YES1
    67  CD36    YES1
    68  RPL10   YES1
    69  MST1R   YES1
    70  ERBB4   CD44
    71  TYRO3   YES1
    72  ADAM12  YES1
    73  NPHS1   YES1
    74  OCLN    YES1
    75  DLG4    YES1
    76  CD2AP   YES1
    77  TRPV4   YES1
    78  SMURF2  SF3A2
    79  GP6     YES1
    80  TP53BP2 YES1
    81  TIAM1   CD44
    82  SP1     REL
    83  ELF1    REL
    84  SMURF2  ACOX3
    85  SMURF2  RNF111
    86  NKRF    REL
    87  TBP     REL
    88  SMURF2  TMEM139
    89  SMURF2  LAPTM5
    90  MAPK8   REL
    91  SMURF2  SNRNP70
    92  DMP1    CD44
    93  PPP4C   REL
    94  NUP155  ZFYVE9
    95  SUMF2   ZFYVE9
    96  ETS2    ZFYVE9
    97  SMAD7   ZNF107
    98  SMAD7   ZBTB44
    99  SMAD7   TTF2
    100 HSPA8   REL
    101 SMAD7   MYOD1
    102 GTF2B   REL

Comment: read [this on CV](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30975/how-to-add-non-linear-trend-line-to-a-scatter-plot-in-r) and [this on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23334360/plot-polynomial-regression-curve-in-r), that should help you

Comment: Thanks Jota, but that line is not effect it will not plot any line on the curve.

Comment: Please post a [MWE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you plot using `ggplot2`, you can just add [`geom_smooth`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_smooth.html) (for example using `loess` or `gam`) to your data.