# How to plot fitted polynomial in R?

Tags: r, polynomials

I have a `parametric polynomial regression` in `R`, that I fitted to my data like so:

```
poly_model <- lm(mydataframef$y ~ poly(mydataframe$x,degree=5))
```

`mydf` obviously contains `y` and `x`.  Then I plot it like this

```
plot(mydataframe$x, mydataframe$y, xlab='regressor or predictor variable polynomial regression', ylab='outcome or label')
```

Then I want to add the polynomial that was fitted, so I do the following:

```
abline(poly_model)
```

This gives me a warning: 
`Warning message:
In abline(poly_model) :
  only using the first two of 6 regression coefficients`

Of course, the plot is all out of wack because , as promised it only uses the first two, which are the intercept and slope.  Why would it be only using the first two coefficients, when I only have one predictor variable?  So, the plot should be 2-d anyway?  Confused.  Thanks.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23334360/plot-polynomial-regression-curve-in-r) link help ?

Comment: Come up with a range of x values, use `predict` to generate the y values and plot them. `newx = seq(min(dat$x), max(dat$x), length.out = 100); newdat = data.frame(newx = newx); newdat$newy predict(poly_model, newdata = newdat); with(newdat, plot(newx, newy, type = "l")`.

Comment: Trying to use `abline` to plot a polynomial response seems very unwise. `abline` is for , well, ... lines. Ironically what you probably want is the `lines` function which will draw curves.

Comment: Even `lines` actually draws straight lines, but it just connects many of them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the answer,

```
poly_model <- lm(mpg ~ poly(hp,degree=5), data = mtcars)

x <- with(mtcars, seq(min(hp), max(hp), length.out=2000))
y <- predict(poly_model, newdata = data.frame(hp = x))

plot(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)
lines(x, y, col = "red")
```

The Output Plot is,

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `fitted`.  Using the builtin data.frame `BOD`:

```
fm <- lm(demand ~ poly(Time, 3), BOD)
plot(demand ~ Time, BOD)
lines(fitted(fm) ~ Time, BOD, col = "red")
```

giving:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This doesn't seem to fit a polynomial.  Is it some sort of spline regression?

Comment: The fit here is what the question asked for and is the same as in the other answer (modulo the data set and degree).

Comment: I see now that it is because the number of dots connected is fewer, so it looks choppy, but it is correct.  Thanks!